# Referencing a struct within a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a C struct generated by an external tool. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct externalStruct{
    int  msgID;
    struct internalStruct {     
        long someValue;
    } *internalStruct ;
} externalStruct_t;
```

Do the following leaves internalStruct pointed to some random value on the heap:

```
externalStruct_t* newExternalStruct = new externalStruct_t;
```

So here's my question:

How do I properly instantiate the pointer "internalStruct"?

Comment: You can't use `new` to instantiate anything in C, did you perhaps mean C++?

Comment: `new` in C? Do you mean C++, or are you looking for `malloc(sizeof(externalStruct_t))`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in C ([C99 demo](http://ideone.com/fE0kWc)):

```
externalStruct_t* newExternalStruct = malloc(sizeof(externalStruct_t));
newExternalStruct->internalStruct = malloc(sizeof(*newExternalStruct->internalStruct));
```

In C++ you would need to insert casts ([C++ demo](http://ideone.com/wk2Rqx)):

```
externalStruct_t* newExternalStruct = new externalStruct_t;
// You need to rename internalStruct to internalStructType
// to avoid a naming collision:
newExternalStruct->internalStruct = new externalStruct::internalStructType;
```

Comment: I tried that and the error I get is:

error: expected type-specifier
error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'externalStruct::internalStruct*' in assignment
error: expected ';'

Comment: @TonyHuy I just fixed that - take a look at the demo. The error is because the name of the type and the name of the member are the same. Can you change the tool to produce a different name for the type or for the field?